# imported c# cmdlet not working

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

There are multiple project in my solution, one of which contains a class = basically a C# Module to be used via Power Shell console:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management;
using EDZ.DAL;
using EDZ.Model;
using System.Collections;

namespace AddUser
{
  [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "User")]
  class AddUser : Cmdlet
  {
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
      WriteObject("test string");
    }
    //public AddUser(IRepository<IEntity> irepo)
    //{
    //  repoUser = (RepositoryBase<User>)irepo;
    //}
    //RepositoryBase<User> repoUser;

    //RepositoryBase<User> repoUser = new RepositoryBase<User>();

    //[Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 1)]
    //public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    //[Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 2)]
    //public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //[Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 3)]
    //public string LastName { get; set; }

    //[Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 4)]
    //public string Title { get; set; }

    //[Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 5)]
    //public string Email { get; set; }

    //[Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 6)]
    //public Guid ExpertId { get; set; }

    //[Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 7)]
    //public Guid IdentityId { get; set; }
    //protected override void ProcessRecord()
    //{
    //  //try {
    //    User user = new User() { FirstName = this.FirstName, LastName = this.LastName, Title = this.Title, Email = this.Email, ExpertId = this.ExpertId, IdentityId = this.IdentityId };

    //    repoUser.Add(UserID, user);
    //  //}
    //  //catch(Exception ex)
    //  //{
    //  //  WriteObject("something's wrong: " + ex.Message);
    //  //}
    //  IEnumerable tempList = repoUser.GetAll();
    //  foreach(User u in tempList)
    //  {
    //    WriteObject(u);
    //  }
    //}
  }
}
```

What I did:

1. built the solution and copied the path of the AddUser.dll
2. opened the PS console as Administrator
3. successfully imported the AddUser.dll -> when I check it via Get-Module command, AddUser is present in the Name column. Although, there is nothing in the ExportedCommands column in the same row...could that be the issue?
4. When I write the Add-User command, I expect  to display the "test string", but I get this error:

Add-User : The term 'Add-User' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
 or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-User
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-User:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class implementing cmdlet should be `public` or it will not be exported as command. As you does not use any explicit access modifier, your `AddUser` class is `internal`. You should make it `public`:

```
public class AddUser : Cmdlet
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I was trying to find the bug all day yesterday...this has to be the lamest, dumbest mistake I have ever made...thanks again.